# Ajax request sends numbers as string

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I want to send different numbers as number and not as string via AJAX post. I am aware, that ajax requests / the http protocol is not type-safe and thus I created a JSON object, but on the serverside it's still received as string.

```
var node = $(this);
var id = parseInt(node.data("id"));
var isActive = node.is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
var jsonParam = {Id: id, IsActive: isActive};

$.ajax({
  url: "/accounts/edit-account",
  type: "POST",
  data: jsonParam,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (response)
  {

  },
  error: function (xhr) {
    alert("Error while updating the account");
  }
});
```

Returns:

```
{ Id: '102', IsActive: '1' }
```

**Serversided code:**

```
router.post('/edit-account', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
});
```

Comment: What is the server-side code that processes the JSON sent?

Comment: `console.log(req.body);` - Express.js

Comment: You have to show us the server-side code that sends the ajax response so we can see exactly what it is doing.  Only then, do we know the appropriate thing for the client to do.

Comment: It's not doing anything but outputting it as I wrote in my comment. The rest is express.js stuff. Anyways I have added it to my question

Comment: @PatrickRoberts since this is a post request I am using body-parser as middleware. I don't think it's a serversided issue at all since serialized formdata works just fine with numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying `contentType: "application/json"` in your AJAX. The `dataType` specifies what is expected from the response, not what's in the request.

Comment: This leads to an exception in node: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token I`. According to another SO post it is throwing because it's already a json object

Comment: Try calling `JSON.stringify` on `jsonParam` then?

Answer (score 0):

Just use parseInt on the returned string:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: I have already tried that without success. I have edited my code in the question

Comment: Now I have tried so and it works, but I want to achieve that this is done clientsided.